# How to get ownership of QClipboard

Tags: python, pyqt5, windows-10, qclipboard

I'm using PyQt 5.15 and python 3.10 on Windows 10.
In my application I have a loop which checks if there is a image in the `QClipboard`. After reading it I like to `clear` the clipboard and wait for the next image which will be copied by the user from any other application (like screenshot etc.)

But after `QApplication.clipboard().clear(QClipboard.Clipboard)` the pixmap is not deleted and still has its old size. Tested with `QApplication.clipboard().pixmap().height()`

The call of `QApplication.clipboard().ownsClipboard()` returns allways `False`, so I think I have to take the ownership of the clipboard. I can't find any reference to do that.

According to the documentation:

```
bool QClipboard::ownsClipboard() const

Returns true if this clipboard object owns the clipboard data; otherwise returns false.
```

I think the data in the clipboard are protected by the application where I copied the data from. So, how can I get this ownership?

I found some information on this site: [How ownership of the Windows clipboard is tracked in Win32](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210526-00/?p=105252), but I have no idea how to adapt this to python.

The basic working loop is like this:

```
def copyloop(self):
    clipboard = QGuiApplication.clipboard()
    mimeData = clipboard.mimeData (QClipboard.Clipboard)
    loop = True
    while loop:
        if mimeData.hasImage ():
            pixmap = QPixmap(mimeData.imageData ())
            # do something with pixmap
            #self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Clip me", "before clear clipboard: " + str(clipboard.pixmap(QClipboard.Clipboard).width()))
            clipboard.clear(QClipboard.Clipboard)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Clip me", "After clear clipboard: " + str(clipboard.pixmap(QClipboard.Clipboard).width()))
            loop = False
        else:
            #self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap())
            loop = True
```

The code works as long as I use it in standalone (simple GUI with one QDialog class), but in my programm (Stacked layouts with QMainwindow's and mutiple Dialogs) it doesn't clear the clipboard.

**EDIT:**

Working loop including comment of @Musicamente:

```
        while  pushButton.isChecked():
            mimeData = clipboard.mimeData()
            if mimeData.hasImage ():
                pixmap = QPixmap(mimeData.imageData ())
                # do something with pixmap
            QApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: Why do you use a possibly infinite and blocking while loop in a gui program?

Comment: It is only a loop for short example. I use `pushbutton.isChecked()` in the program.

Comment: That loop cannot work properly, since you're always processing the *same* mimedata, and even if you updated that by reading again the clipboard, the loop would prevent proper behavior since it doesn't allow the Qt event loop to process events (and, thus, reading/clearing the clipboard). If it works in one case and not in the other, then it means that the problem is elsewhere. Please provide a proper [mre], we cannot debug invalid code that can *not* reproduce the issue.

Comment: The mimeData are updated by external program, so that is not the reason (tested). But I found another 'bug' in my structure, which leads me to other things first...
But the question is still, how to get the `ownership` of the `clipboard` which may be the path to the solution in my point of view. 

From the docs:
`There is a single QClipboard object in an application, accessible as clipboard()` 
In my understanding I have to intialize this in every function I use it by `clipboard = QGuiApplication.clipboard()`. Its exacly what I am doing. And the behavior is independent where I call it.

Comment: The pointer to the mimeData might become invalid, so you should *always* retrieve the mimeData if using a loop, which shouldn't be used like this anyway exactly because it prevents *proper* event processing (which, as said, might be the reason of your inconsistency). As said, if this is not the implementation you're using, we cannot be sure about your actual problem. Besides, looking at the QClipboard implementation, it seems that some time (aka, event queue processing) is required for the clipboard to be properly updated. You *might* try adding a `QApplication.processEvents()` after clearing.

Comment: The problem was multiple import of numpy, the answer to the question is below.

Comment: and the fact that pywinauto blocks the clipboard

Comment: 1. I really don't see what a multiple import of numpy would have to do with a clipboard issue; 2. your answer has no mention about numpy; 3. the ownership of the clipboard doesn't prevent other application to get *their ownership*, and your "it's not possible to set it" doesn't make any sense as Qt has absolutely no problem in taking ownership by clearing; 4. if the problem was pywinauto, numpy (as said above) has absolutely nothing to do with it; 5. whether the problem was that or another, it demonstrates ***again*** that without a MRE we cannot provide answers to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [MS Windows App development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardowner)

> In general, the clipboard owner is the window that last placed data in
> clipboard. The EmptyClipboard function assigns clipboard ownership.

Seems to be the nearest answer.

Therefore its not possible to set it ;-)

**EDIT:**

Finally I got a maximum reduced sample to demonstrate the fault:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# if the following import is used, QApplication.clipboard() will not work as expected. 
# comment it out, copy any text and run. Enjoy the different output

from pywinauto import application


def clipboard_test():
    print("-> clipboard_test")
    clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
    print("Owner                    =", clipboard.ownsClipboard())
    print("before clear             =", clipboard.text(mode=clipboard.Clipboard))
    clipboard.clear(clipboard.Clipboard)
    QApplication.processEvents()
    print("after clear              =", clipboard.text(mode=clipboard.Clipboard))
    clipboard.setText(":-)", mode=clipboard.Clipboard)
    print("new content (should ;-)) =", clipboard.text(mode=clipboard.Clipboard))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clipboard_test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```